# Backend not showing

Tags: wordpress

I’m trying to install a copy of my live wordpress site (crafty-stuff.com) on my local system running win10 & wamp.

Have downloaded wp-content (through filezilla) and have a copy of the live database (phpmyadmin) with switched out urls(notepad++).

So the site is working OK – all content seems to be showing up at http://localhost/crafty-stuff for me, with just the nav and site banner needing a fix, but when I try to login into the backend “http://localhost/crafty-stuff/wp-login.php” I just get to my home page with a wordpress bar/taskbar on top, but with no way/link on it to get to the add posts and pages management backend area.

If I clear the database (drop all tables) and remove wp-config.php I can get to the backend OK after a fresh(to blank WordPress) install procedure.

So thinking my copy of the database is somehow wrong, for if I then drop the blank database tables and import the hosted site’s .sql (with altered urls) I again lose the backend.

Navigating to http://localhost/crafty-stuff/wp-admin/ manually when logged in, gives “Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.” if that is the url for the backend.

Any help?

Comment: Did you put `<?php wp_meta(); ?> `  into your header?

Comment: Searched for it and found 1:

http://crafty-stuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Got it working – had to separate all tables in the hosted db into single import files(one for each table), do a clean blank WordPress install, and drop then import each of the tables separately until I got a problem login into the backend.

Something in wp_usermeta was the problem, so did an install of the hosted site’s full db, dropped the wp_usermeta and imported another version from a clean blank WordPress.

Not yet capable of going through the wp_usermeta to see if I can work out the problem fully.

Thanks for the help guys anyway :)